# J Query stopping mod_djimageslider in Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, module

I've got a website, where the client wants testimonials to change every few seconds, so I have built a simple script using J Query. All works fine, but having the Google hosted J Query is stopping the images in another element from loading. Does anyone have any idea why this maybe?

The current page where you can see it : (CSS is a little skewed at the moment I know)
http://www.pressbeau.co.uk/tithe-farm-nursing-home/

Getting the J Query (Have I done this wrong? - It does work and do its job fading through the elements but stops the other unrelated images from loading...)

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
      // This Script loads the J Query File
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this below the line where you're loading jQuery ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
// This Script loads the J Query File
jQuery.noConflict();
```

If tou can't do that (because of using joomla) save jquery.min.js locally and add the above line at the end of that file.

Comment: Tried that, and it half works, in that is solves the orginal issue, but now my elements which fade in and out don't - like its stopped my script running now? Any ideas? - I put "jQuery.noConflict();" in the local file

Comment: This is the end of the J Query local file - is it right like this?    ...,[],function(){return f})})(window);jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code instead of embeding the script as is.

```
if (!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')) {
        JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery', true);
        // add jQuery from Google library
        $document->addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
}
```

Comment: This has the same issue as the other answer, it just seams to stop my script from working? I've added it as such, does it look right (I'm newbie with JS)     <script type="text/javascript">
 if (!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')) {
        JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery', true);
        // add jQuery from Google library
        $document->addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
}
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

I've found (thanks to research done due to the 2 answers I received), it was a conflict between J Query library and another JavaScript library within the site.

For future reference to solve the problem, after you call the J Query Library place in this code:
`<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>`

This disables the jQuery shortcut "$" so any intances where you call a jQuery function with $ you need to replace with jQuery

So this is before

```
$("#???").fadeIn(speed, timerChangeTwo);
```

And this is after the change

```
jQuery("#???").fadeIn(speed, timerChangeTwo);
```

That should then solve the problem - hope someone else finds the useful!